# ImageView doesn't rescale Image to selected size

Tags: android, layout, resize, imageview, layoutparams

I'm using a ImageView with a fixed size for adding an icon to a menu. In my application, I use it a lot of times, but on this ImageView the Layout Params seem to not work.
Unlike the others ImageViews, in this case, I'm using a template directly, but I think that's not the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_dark"
    android:contentDescription="ICON" />
```

Its been used in code as follows.

```
ImageView iview =(ImageView) View.inflate(context, R.layout.icon, null);
```

Theoretically, It should resize automatically the image, however, the images continues with the original size, although the size was `1dp`. Where is the problem? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3126959/466938

Answer (score 0):

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

you should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ImageView assignment of the resource from src to background.